# come over/ come over to

Tags: meaning

**1 Do you want to come over after school today?** means to visit.

What does "come over to" mean? Does it mean the same as "come over"?

> 2 Do you want to come over **to me** after school today?
>
> 3 Do you want to come over **to my home** after school today?

Comment: In the context of Sentence 1, _come over_ implies _come to my home_. If you are naming the intended destination, you need to include _to_.

Comment: Generally, to my house rather than to my home. come/go **to a place**, not to a person, because that would change the meaning. I would use home in a different context: I invited them to my home and they stole all my money.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they mean the same. But, in your second sentence, you don't need to say "to me". It's redundant because the word "over" already implies your location. Still, you can use it to be clearer, especially if the listener might not know where you live.

The last sentence is clear, but you can still leave out "to my home".

(If you just use come over + sb, it means "to affect someone"
Example: I'm sorry! That was a stupid thing to say - I don't know what came over me.)